# Check if value of ColumnA is in ColumnB if parameter is not null (SQL-Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use an sql statement which checks if a parameter in my function is null. If it is null, it should do nothing else, but if it isn't null it should check if a certain value from one column appears in an other column.

So it should be something like that

```
SELECT * FROM TableA 
WHERE User IN (SELECT User FROM TableB WHERE Condition = @ParameterA) 
AND File IN (SELECT File FROM TableB WHERE Condition = @ParameterB)
```

So, what I want now is to check if `@ParameterA` is null. If it is, it should not do the `User IN [...]` and if `@ParameterB` is null, it should not do the `File IN [...]`

I tried things like these:

```
WHERE (@paramA IS NULL AND A.User = A.User)
OR (@paramA IS NOT NULL AND A.User IN (Select User FROM TableB WHERE Condition = @paramA))
AND(@paramB IS NULL AND A.File = A.File)
OR (@paramB IS NOT NULL AND A.File IN (Select File FROM TableB WHERE Condition = @paramB))
```

But that doesn't return the results I am expecting... Any ideas?

Comment: please post some sample data and explain ,you also look here for how to ask :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: So, both conditions should be applied (`A.User IN` and `A.File IN`) only if `@ParamA` and `@ParamB` are not `NULL`, right? If this is the case then you need additional parantheses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
SELECT * FROM TableA 
WHERE (@ParameterA IS NULL OR  User IN (SELECT User FROM TableB WHERE Condition = @ParameterA)) 
  AND 
      (@ParamterB IS NULL OR File IN (SELECT File FROM TableB WHERE Condition = @ParameterB))
```

The first condition will be true if either the given param is null `OR` the IN-condition is fullfilled. The second condition does the same... Both must be true due to the combining `AND`

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Well, if they are `NULL`, the IN clause will never be true, as the value cannot be found in the list. So the `IS NULL` combined with `OR` makes it possible, to return `true` in case of the parameter being `NULL`. Don't you think so?

Comment: Aaaah of course! I was so close to this solution. Why am I always thinking too complicated. That solution is working fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would usually use a case statement but since you are comparing more than one value in your where clauses, using `IN`  i would check this at the beginning of the statement. Also, you stated that if the parameter is `NULL` it should do nothing, thus something like `WHERE @ParameterA is null or User in ...` wouldn't fit your solution since if it was `NULL` it would return everything...

```
IF @ParameterA IS NOT NULL AND @ParameterB IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM TableA 
WHERE User = IN (SELECT User FROM TableB WHERE Condition = @ParameterA) 
AND File IN (SELECT File FROM TableB WHERE Condition = @ParameterB)

END
ELSE BEGIN
SELECT 'Your Param is NULL'
END
```